# get .dat file content php

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

i have a program to upload a .dat file that contains text with codeigniter.

here's the code of upload form:

view

```
<div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Upload</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">    
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('report/coba_upload');?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id">
                <input type="file" name="file_1" size="20" class="form-control"/><br /><br />
                <button type="submit" name="btn_upload" class="btn btn-primary">UPLOAD</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's a code of controller to proccess the upload:

```
function coba_upload(){
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $file = $_FILES['file_1']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file_1']['tmp_name'];
        $folder = "./upload/honor/";
        $this->upload->do_upload("file_1");
        if (move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder . $file)) {
            $handle = fopen("./upload/honor/$file", "r");
            if ($handle) {
                while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
                    echo $buffer;
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }

        } else {
            echo 'upload failed';
        }
    }
```

here's an example of input file (.dat file) :

```
GLC002                                  LABA RUGI KONSOLIDASI                                                       PAGE:   1
    BANK XXX                             AS AT MAY 31, 2016                                            RUN DATE: 06/06/2016
                                                   0788 DIV. XXX

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SANDI     NAMA REKENING                           SALDO VALAS DLM RUPIAH       SALDO DALAM RUPIAH         SALDO GABUNGAN
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              PENDAPATAN

    4.1       PENDAPATAN BUNGA                                                          28,012,902.00           28,012,902.00
    4.2       PENDAPATAN PROPISI & KOMISI
    4.3       KEUNTGN TRANSAKSI SURAT BERHARGA
    4.4       KEUNTGN/KRG TRANSAKSI VALAS & DERIVATIF
    4.8       PENDAPATAN OPERASIONAL LAINNYA
    4.9       PENDAPATAN NON OPERASIONAL                                               304,282,764.00          304,282,764.00
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              TOTAL PENDAPATAN                                                         332,295,666.00          332,295,666.00
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but the output turns into one line

```
GLC002 LABA RUGI KONSOLIDASI PAGE: 1 BANK NEGARA INDONESIA AS AT MAY 31, 2016 RUN DATE: 06/06/2016 0788 DIV. ORGANIZATIONAL LEARNING -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- SANDI NAMA REKENING SALDO VALAS DLM RUPIAH SALDO DALAM RUPIAH SALDO GABUNGAN -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- PENDAPATAN 4.1 PENDAPATAN BUNGA 28,012,902.00 28,012,902.00 4.2 PENDAPATAN PROPISI & KOMISI 4.3 KEUNTGN TRANSAKSI SURAT BERHARGA 4.4 KEUNTGN/KRG TRANSAKSI VALAS & DERIVATIF 4.8 PENDAPATAN OPERASIONAL LAINNYA 4.9 PENDAPATAN NON OPERASIONAL 304,282,764.00 304,282,764.00 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- TOTAL PENDAPATAN 332,295,666.00 332,295,666.00 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- BEBAN 5.1 BEBAN BUNGA 5.2 BEBAN PROPISI & KOMISI 5.3 BEBAN PENYISIHAN KERUGIAN 6,333,036.01- 6,333,036.01- 5.5 BEBAN ADMINISTRASI DAN UMUM 62,029,442,518.19- 62,029,442,518.19- 5.6 KERUGIAN TRANSAKSI SURAT BERHARGA 5.7 KRG TRX VALAS DAN DERIVATIF 5.8 BEBAN OPERASIONAL LAINNYA 500,000.00- 500,000.00- 5.9 BEBAN NON OPERASIONAL -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- TOTAL BIAYA 62,036,275,554.20- 62,036,275,554.20- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- LABA/RUGI TAHUN BERJALAN 61,703,979,888.20- 61,703,979,888.20- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- PT BANK XXX
```

the question is:

1. what function to get output same as the original file (not only one
   line)?
2. how to get specific text based of its position (column and row) and converted them to array and insert into database sql?

sorry if this question is too basic but i have been stuck and did not get what I need. please give me a solution.

thank you for your attention and kindness

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a **<pre>** tag

```
<pre>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('report/coba_upload');?>
</pre>
```

Another approach would be to use **nl2br**

```
<?php echo nl2br(form_open_multipart('report/coba_upload'));?>
```

Comment: You may need to check what character is being used for end of line - whether it is a carriage return, line feed or both.